# Blender to Unreal or Unity - will combining animations into one clip for a parent object to store effect workflow?

Tags: unity, blender, unreal, unreal-4

Hey so I have a gun and a set of rigged hands in blender, and I was wondering if I made a parent object for the gun, hands and everything, took all the animations respectively (such as right hand reload, left hand reload, gun reload, etc) and combined them all into one animation called reload, would there be problems in the future when working in Unreal or Unity? Would I be able to apply the same animation to all the objects that are a part of the action and have them work respectively?

Comment: I think that would be fine for Unity, though you might have to tweak the import -> animation settings.  It usually sees only one animation and smooshes things together.  Best bet is to do something simple and import it and see if it works.

Comment: Unreal it would be fine too? and yea that's a good idea I'll try something simple. Although I literally just downloaded unreal and have no idea how to use it so that'll have to wait

Comment: No idea about Unreal, never used it.

Comment: @Draco18s so How do I give an action 2+ location values, because when I have the parent container object containing all the keyframes of all the other objects as chilldren, one will overwrite the other. So now what?

Comment: I am not sure, that's what the simple test was for.  I am not a modeler and the few times I had to deal with imported animations, that was actually handled by someone else (we still had the occasional hiccup).  I suspect that in this may be the thing that answers your question for you.